# How can I get XML attributes and values from an RSS feed in Python?

Tags: python, rss

I'm using the Yahoo! Weather API to retrieve some values. This is the request:

[Los Angeles Weather](http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2442047&u=c)

How can I get attributes and values from the following:

```
<yweather:astronomy sunrise="6:20 am" sunset="4:52 pm"/>
<yweather:condition text="Partly Cloudy" code="29" temp="14" date="Fri, 09 Nov 2012 1:47 am PST"/>
```

I want to print something like:

```
Sunrise: 6.20 am
Sunset: 4.52 pm
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `feedparser` library:

```
import feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2442047&u=c')
print 'Sunrise:', feed.feed.yweather_astronomy['sunrise']
print 'Sunset:', feed.feed.yweather_astronomy['sunset']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`feedparser`](http://packages.python.org/feedparser/):

```
import feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2442047&u=c')
sunrise = feed.items()[0][1]["yweather_astronomy"]["sunrise"]
sunset = feed.items()[0][1]["yweather_astronomy"]["sunset"]
```

Play with the result of `parse` to get a feeling for the structure of the parsed feed.

Comment: @sarbo But the answer by James Henstridge is even better.