# How to pull out and then print certain words from a link

Tags: python, string

I am making a weather report program for homework, and it needs to print:

`Today's temperatures: maximum 2ºC, minimum -1ºC`

currently it prints out:

```
Today's temperatures:      <title>Thursday: Light Snow Shower, Maximum 
Temperature: 2Â°C (36Â°F) Minimum Temperature: -1Â°C (30Â°F)</title>.
```

How do I ensure it only prints the correct information? This is my code:

```
import urllib

url = 'http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2654993/3dayforecast.rss'
web_connection = urllib.urlopen(url)

for line in web_connection.readlines():
    if line.find('Thursday:') != -1:
        print "Today's temperatures:" + line

web_connection.close()
```

Comment: could you precise what are you expecting ? what  is the problem ?

Comment: Perhaps these question might help you get the answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306438/how-can-i-get-xml-attributes-and-values-from-an-rss-feed-in-python

Comment: I would suggest you to use regular expressions to parse the output of the link. Let them regex group the output, so you can decide which parts of the parsed output is the one you want to print.

Comment: Are you required to use the RSS feed for this assignment? If not, you might find it easier to use the [JSON feed](http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2654993/3dayforecast.json), especially if you're familiar with Python's dictionaries. The standard `json` module makes it pretty easy to work with data in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to do so

```
import re

TEMP_REGEX = "^.*Maximum\s+Temperature:\s+(?P<max>([+-]?[0-9]*[\.,]?[0-9]*)).*Minimum\s+Temperature:\s+(?P<min>([+-]?[0-9]*[\.,]?[0-9]*)).*$"

matched = re.match(TEMP_REGEX, line)

if matched:
    max = matched.groupdict()["max"]
    min = matched.groupdict()["min"]

.....
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is to parse the RSS file, which is in XML format. You can start by studying the XML module documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Here's a small code snippet to get you started:

```
import urllib
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2654993/3dayforecast.rss'
web_conn = urllib.urlopen(url)
rss = web_conn.read()
web_conn.close()

weather_data = ET.fromstring(rss)
for node in weather_data.iter():
    if node.tag == "item":
        title = node.find("title").text
        if title.find("Thursday") != -1:
            todays_weather = node.find("description").text.split(',')
            for entry in todays_weather:
                print entry.strip()
```

This outputs:

```
Maximum Temperature: 2°C (36°F)
Minimum Temperature: -1°C (30°F)
Wind Direction: Westerly
Wind Speed: 6mph
Visibility: Very Good
Pressure: 977mb
Humidity: 87%
UV Risk: 1
Pollution: Low
Sunrise: 07:59 GMT
Sunset: 16:42 GMT
```

**How and why?**
If you open the RSS file in your browser, you'll see that it's XML formatted, which means that it has a particular structure. Looking at the information, you see that each day's forecast is packed in an `<item>` that has a `<title>` and `<description>` among other information. By using an XML parser, you'll be able to easily navigate through the structure with intuitive methods as .`find()`, `.findall()` and reach the data with the `.text` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems to solve, first find the name of the day in the week second find the right line with minimum and maximum temp and third parse these temps.
I think this should work:

```
import urllib
import re

url = 'http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2654993/3dayforecast.rss'
web_connection = urllib.urlopen(url)

for line in web_connection.readlines():
    day_of_the_week = time.strftime("%A")
    if '<title>'+ day_of_the_week +':' in line:
        m = re.match('.+Maximum Temperature:\s(.+)°C.+Minimum Temperature:\s(.+)°C.+', line)
        max_temp = m.group(1)
        min_temp = m.group(2)
print("Today's temperatures: maximum " + max_temp + "°C, minimum " + min_temp + "°C")

web_connection.close()
```

So to get the day of the week look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

Then i did the same as you to find the right line (just used the 'in' statement of Python)

And afterwards i applied a regexp with groups to parse the numbers (and signs!). To help you with regexp design you could try https://regex101.com/#python

Have fun!